# Addition and Subtraction of large ints without Math.BigInteger

Tags: java, stack, biginteger, addition, subtraction

Alright, so I have been assigned an exercise in using stacks. The challenge for this assignment is to create a program that can add and subtract extremely large integers (presumably of infinite size) without using any libraries or imports (e.g no BigInteger).

This is how I approached addition:

---

```
public Stack<Integer> sum(Stack<Integer> leadingStack, Stack<Integer> secondStack) {
    int carry = 0;
    Stack<Integer> resultStack = new Stack<Integer>();
    while (leadingStack.isEmpty() == false && secondStack.isEmpty() == false) {
        int result = 0;
        int dig1 = leadingStack.pop();
        int dig2 = secondStack.pop();
        int resultDig = 0;

        result = dig1 + dig2 + carry;
        resultDig = result % 10;
        carry = result / 10;
        resultStack.push(resultDig);
    }
    if (carry > 0)
        resultStack.push(carry);
    return resultStack;
}
```

This method appears to work with some integers and not others. For example, if I input 500 & 450, I get 950 as expected. However, if I input 500 and 45, I get 45.

---

And this is how I approached subtraction (very similar approach):

---

```
    public Stack<Integer> sub(Stack<Integer> leadingStack, Stack<Integer> secondStack) {
    boolean borrow = false;
    Stack<Integer> resultStack = new Stack<Integer>();
    while (leadingStack.isEmpty() == false && secondStack.isEmpty() == false) {
        int dig1 = leadingStack.pop();
        int dig2 = secondStack.pop();
        if (borrow = true) {
            dig1 -= 1;
            borrow = false;
        }
        if (dig1 - dig2 < 0) {
            dig1 += 10;
            resultStack.push(dig1 - dig2);
            borrow = true;
        }
    }
    return resultStack;
}
```

This has a very similar issue. For example, if I subtract 50 and 45, I get 4. if I subtract 50,000 and 45,000 I get 4,900.

---

I am sure I am missing something simple here, but I have looked over the code over and over and I am not sure what it is.

Comment: Focus on one part at a time. Use a debugger to step through your code and view the values of variables at each step. Debugging is an important skill and can only be learned by doing.

Comment: Pay close attention to how your add() method handles numbers with differing numbers of digits.

Comment: Aren't you "using a library" when you use `java.util.Stack`?

Comment: There is no need to use == to compare boolean values since the result is a boolean which you already have to begin with. `x == true` is the same as just `x`. `x == false` is the same as `!x`.

Comment: Also be sure you know the difference between = and ==.

Comment: What is the purpose of `if (borrow = true)`, or did you perhaps mean `if (borrow == true)`, aka `if (borrow)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few places in your code that need attention:

- If stacks have different size, the remaining part of a bigger stack is not handled
- When returning the result stack, its elements has to be reversed as the smallest position digit is pushed first (and bigger position last)
- Mixed assignment operator with equality at `if (borrow = true)`
- Subtraction method does not handle negative numbers

All together in code:

```
public Stack<Integer> sum(Stack<Integer> leadingStack, Stack<Integer> secondStack) {
  int carry = 0;
  Stack<Integer> resultStack = new Stack<Integer>();
  while (leadingStack.isEmpty() == false && secondStack.isEmpty() == false) {
    int dig1 = leadingStack.pop();
    int dig2 = secondStack.pop();
    int result = dig1 + dig2 + carry;
    int resultDig = result % 10;
    carry = result / 10;
    resultStack.push(resultDig);
  }

  Stack<Integer> leftStack = leadingStack.isEmpty() ? secondStack : leadingStack;
  while (leftStack.isEmpty() == false) {
    int dig = leftStack.pop();
    if (carry > 0) {
        dig += carry;
        carry = 0;
    }
    resultStack.push(dig);
  }

  if (carry > 0) resultStack.push(carry);
  return reverse(resultStack);
}

public Stack<Integer> sub(Stack<Integer> leadingStack, Stack<Integer> secondStack) {
  boolean borrow = false;
  Stack<Integer> resultStack = new Stack<Integer>();

  if (leadingStack.size() < secondStack.size()) {
    // Handle negative number
  }
  while (leadingStack.isEmpty() == false && secondStack.isEmpty() == false) {
    int dig1 = leadingStack.pop();
    int dig2 = secondStack.pop();
    if (borrow) {
        dig1 -= 1;
        borrow = false;
    }
    if (dig1 < dig2) {
        dig1 += 10;
        resultStack.push(dig1 - dig2);
        borrow = true;
    }
    else {
        resultStack.push(dig1 - dig2);
    }
  } 

  Stack<Integer> leftStack = leadingStack.isEmpty() ? secondStack : leadingStack;
  while (leftStack.isEmpty() == false) {
    int dig = leftStack.pop();
    if (borrow) {
      dig -= 1; 
      borrow = false;
    }
    resultStack.push(dig);
  }

  if (borrow) {
    // Handle negative number
  }
  return reverse(resultStack);
}

private Stack<Integer> reverse(Stack<Integer> inStack) {
  Stack<Integer> outStack = new Stack<>();
   while (inStack.isEmpty() == false) outStack.push(inStack.pop());
   return outStack;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! those were all obvious issues with my code. I implemented the leftStack part of the code, and all seems well. I am not sure how I forgot to handle the different size of each stack.

Comment: @Quinn Can you let everyone know how did you handle negative numbers?

Answer (score 0):

I'd start taking a look at this condition:

```
while (leadingStack.isEmpty() == false && secondStack.isEmpty() == false)
```

This means "while both stacks are not empty". But if you have 2 numbers with different number of digits (let's say 500 and 45), it fails (because one stack will be empty and the other won't, leaving the loop before processing all digits). So you should change the condition to "while at least one stack is not empty":

```
while (leadingStack.isEmpty() == false || secondStack.isEmpty() == false)
```

Another tip: as `isEmpty()` returns a boolean, you don't need to compare using `==`, you could do:

```
while (! leadingStack.isEmpty() || ! secondStack.isEmpty())
```

Note that, as one stack might be empty while the other isn't, you should check if it's empty before calling `pop`:

```
int dig1 = 0;
if (!leadingStack.isEmpty()) {
    dig1 = leadingStack.pop();
}
int dig2 = 0;
if (!secondStack.isEmpty()) {
    dig2 = secondStack.pop();
}
```

Comment: Don't compare booleans to boolean literals to get a boolean because just the boolean is enough.

Comment: @LewBloch I also explain that in the answer

Comment: Yes, you did. Sorry for the redundancy.